# Set variable value as key in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I couldn't add the variable value as my key name in backbone.js is there any way to do this ?? look at the code below

```
(function ($) {

    Today = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
    }); 
    var data= ['a','b','c'];
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
          today.set({i:data[i]});
    } 


} (jQuery));
```

how i am able to do that ?

Comment: What kind of data you have? More code please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to simply pass `data` to [`today.set()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set).

```
var data = ['a','b','c'];

var today = new Today();
today.set(data);

console.log(today.attributes);
// {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"}
```

Though, to explain the problem: Identifiers on the left-hand of `:` in [Object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals) always become the key's name themselves. To use a variable's value as a key, you have to use [bracket member operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation).

```
var tmp = {};
tmp[i] = data[i];
today.set(tmp);
```

Comment: Or just use the [two argument form of `set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set): `today.set(i, data[i])`.

Comment: thanks, but when i tried to display the data as  alert(today.0); i was getting an error says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number" ..how should i access that values via  object

Comment: @Josemon JavaScript doesn't allow identifiers to start with numbers. So, for such properties, you'll need to use bracket notation: `alert(today[0])`. You may need to use [`model.attributes`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes): `alert(today.attributes[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

So in javascript an object literal with unquoted key uses the string version of that key:

```
var i=1;
var obj = {i: "this sets obj.i to this string, not obj['1']"};
```

If you want a computed key, follow this pattern:

```
var keyname = i + 'whatever' + 42;
var obj = {};
obj[keyname] = value;
```